# configuration OSPF in OpenBSD5.7

Tags: networking, openbsd, ospf

Yesterday i tried to enable OSPF routing on OpenBSD 5.7 . so i created "/etc/ospfd.conf" and added this codes to it ( just for test )

```
router-id 127.0.0.1

area 0.0.0.0 {
    interface em0
}
```

but after type `/etc/rc.d/ospfd -fd start` i got this logs in terminal

```
doing _rc_parse_conf
doing _rc_quirks
ospfd_flags empty, using default ><
doing _rc_read_runfile
doing rc_check
ospfd
doing rc_start
/etc/ospfd.conf: group writable or world read/writable
doing _rc_rm_runfile
(failed)
```

can any body tell me why i got this ? 
Note : my OpenBSD is running under vitualbox4.3 and host system is Fedora22

Comment: thanks for all answers :D . finally i fixed my problem by this command `chmod 600 /etc/ospfd.conf `

Answer (score 1):

> /etc/ospfd.conf: group writable or world read/writable

means that you have not correct rights for file.

```
chmod 640 /etc/ospfd.conf
```

must help.